# How can you validate that registries.yaml is set properly?

Tags: authentication, k3s

I've set up my `/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml`, how can I confirm it works without doing

```shell
k3s kubectl run c1 --image docker.io/perl:5.30
k3s kubectl logs --follow=true c1
sleep 1
k3s kubectl delete pod c1
```

Is there a more efficient way to test registry authentication for images than having to use k3s run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml` is read by [`k3s ctr` and `k3s crictl`](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/16152/18965). You can validate it works properly with a command like this,

```sh
sudo k3s crictl pull     docker.io/alpine:3
sudo k3s ctr images pull docker.io/library/alpine:3
```